# RCP SWT Eclipse - Clear a composite container

Tags: java, swt, eclipse-rcp

I need your help...
I have a 2 Composite container. One of them with 2 radio button, the first radio button is CHART and the other is REPORT. When the user select chart, a chart is loaded in the second Composite, everything ok but I don´t know how to remove the chart when the user select "report", is there any way to clear or remove it? I tried it but I can´t find a solution.
Thanks!

```
contenedor_chart = new Composite(parent, SWT.NONE);
        contenedor_chart.setLayout(new FillLayout());
        FillLayout filllayout = new FillLayout();
        filllayout.marginWidth = 50;
        filllayout.marginHeight = 50;

        contenedor_chart.setLayout(filllayout);
        CategoryDataset dataset = cbch.createDataset();
        JFreeChart chart = cbch.createChart(dataset);
        final ChartPanel chartPanel = new ChartPanel(chart);
        chartPanel.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(400, 170));
        new ChartComposite(contenedor_chart, SWT.NONE, chart, true);
```

Comment: What kind of chart? How are the components organized? Please post the relevant code.

Comment: Thanks Baz, i put the code

Answer (score 2):

You can just dispose of the control you no longer want by calling its `dispose` method:

```
Control chart = ... chart control

chart.dispose();
```

Just calling `dispose` will not reclaim the space used by the control unless you force the controls to be layed out again. For example to lay out the whole `Shell` use:

```
Shell shell = ... current shell

shell.pack();
```

which lays out the controls in the shell and adjusts the shell size to fit.

If you want to reuse the chart then don't call `dispose` or `pack`. You can just call `setVisible(false)` on the control.

You could also look at using `StackLayout` to layout multiple controls in a `Composite` or use the Eclipse `PageBook` control.

Comment: Thanks Greg, I tried with chart.dispose() and it´s working but now I don´t know how to get the chart again, I mean, if I select the radio button "chart" after I selected "report", the chart doesn´t appears again. I tried with the method "pack" but I suppose I´m doing something wrong. I put part of the code ---> if (boton_listados.isFocusControl()) { chart.dispose();}

Comment: If you call `dispose` you can't use the control again. If you just want to hide it use `setVisible(false)` (and don't call `pack`).

Comment: yes, I also tried with setVisible(false) but I think is not the most properly, because both radio button must display different things, I don´t know if it´s the best way to do that.

Comment: Hi Greg!, thanks again! One question: I´m trying the Stacklayout you recommended me and it works the first time but when I resize the main window of the application, the chart disappear, do you know the reason? I will edit the code for you to see it, I appreciate your help! thanks!